# Which algorithm is helpful in finding shortest path from source to sink in a graph that has all negative edges(cost)?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I'm wanting to find the shortest path from source to sink in a directed graph, that has all negative weights(edges). From the algorithms that I'm aware of I don't think of any algorithm that helps solve problem like this. Dijkstras algorithm fails for graphs with negative edge! and also I don't want to traverse through all nodes.

There are no negative cycles.

Comment: If all edges have negative costs, if there is a cycle, one should never leave it.

Comment: Does your graph have cycles? If so, are you looking for shortest *simple* path (because otherwise you can always get inside a loop and keep decreasing the path weight)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [which algorithm is used to find shortest path from source to sink that has negative edges(cost)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687157/which-algorithm-is-used-to-find-shortest-path-from-source-to-sink-that-has-negat)